# What part of this html/css code makes the menu item highlighted?

Tags: html, css

I'm copying the design of one website for another (I work for the parent of both companies, no copyright issues) and I can't seem to figure out what part of the code makes the menu item you are currently viewing permanently highlighted (see www.aciscargo.co.uk and compare "Home" with "About Us". 
This is the menu section of the HTML code:

```
<ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="/" id="m_home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about-us/" id="m_about-us">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="expand"><a href="#" id="m_register">Register</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/register-freight-forwarder/" id="m_register-freight-forwarder">Register as a forwarder</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/register-broker/" id="m_register-broker">Register as a broker</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="expand"><a href="#" id="m_our-policies">Our Policies</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/freight-forwarder-cargo/" id="m_freight-forwarder-cargo">Freight Forwarder Cargo</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/security/" id="m_security">Security</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact-us/" id="m_contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
```

And this is the CSS code that I think is related to it (I know enough HTML to get by usually, but I have to use a lot of Googling to get by with CSS)

```
#menu {
margin:0 0 12px 0;
padding:0 0 25px 0;
position:relative;
display:block;
list-style:none;
background:url('../_images/menu/menu.jpg') bottom left no-repeat;
}

#menu li {
margin:0;
padding:0;
position:relative;
}

#menu li a {
width:188px;
height:21px;
margin:0;
padding:5px 0 0 9px;
line-height:150%;
display:block;
background:url('../_images/menu/main.jpg') top left no-repeat;
font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#616161;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Use your browser's Dev Tools to answer questions like this. I recommend Chrome's dev tools.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't actually answer that question (not that I can see)

Answer (score 0):

I think the color part would do so

```
color:#616161;
```

It would change the color of the anchor tag inside that list.

Answer (score 0):

It's:
`background:url('../_images/menu/menu.jpg') bottom left no-repeat;`

Versus: `background:url('../_images/menu/main.jpg') top left no-repeat;`

Applied on [this](http://www.aciscargo.co.uk/_images/menu/main.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

The body tag has an id, and the CSS uses this to set the background using !important (menu.css line 96). Each page's body tag has a different id, so the appropriate menu item is set.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its controlled by this section in the menu.css:

```
#header ul li a:hover,
#menu li a:hover,
#b_home #m_home,
#b_home #h_home,
#b_about-us #m_about-us,
#b_register-freight-forwarder #m_register-freight-forwarder,
#b_register-broker #m_register-broker,
#b_freight-forwarder-cargo #m_freight-forwarder-cargo,
#b_freight_liability_policy #m_fre`ight_liability_policy,
#b_security #m_security,
#b_contact-us #m_contact-us,
#b_contact-us #h_contact-us
{
    background-position:bottom left !important;
}
```

In their highlighted state, the menu items have different id's:

```
<li><a href="/" id="b_home">Home</a></li>
```

Whereas non-highlighted items use:

```
 <li><a href="/" id="m_home">Home</a></li>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case for the page that is currently open, the code still says m_home when it is highlighted :S

Comment: On the currently open page, it still matches with the css above via the <body id="b_home"> followed by the <a id="m_home"> (m_home is a child of b_home, so matches the css rule "#b_home #m_home,"